# CDI / Weld SE - @Observes ContainerInitialized doesn't work

Tags: initialization, cdi, bootstrapping, jboss-weld

I have Weld SE, bootstraped this way:

```
   WeldContainer weld = new Weld().initialize();
```

And the following bean

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityManagerStoreImpl implements EntityManagerStore {

  static {   System.out.println(" AAAAAA EMSI static"); }

  public EntityManagerStoreImpl() {
     System.out.println(" AAAAAA EMSI constructor");
  }

  public void init( @Observes ContainerInitialized containerInitialized ) {
      System.out.println(" AAAAAA EMSI init");
  }
  ...
}
```

According to Weld docs, the `init()` method should be called.
But it's not. Other beans are working fine.
What can be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh... I should have read the docs more carefuly.

`ContainerInitialized` is currently **only** fired from StartMain helper class.
I don't like that, I'd expect it to be fired from `Weld.initialize()`.
So I created https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-949

(Pls vote if you share this oppinion with me.)